# How can I produce a colour bar with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, color

I want to produce a horizontal colour bar with colours varying from black and grey to white. I searched the net for a small code but I couldn't find any.

Could you please help produce something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,10,20,...,90}
    \fill[black!\i] (\i mm,0) rectangle ++(10mm,10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain parts of the code `\foreach`, `\i mm,0`, `rectangle ++(10mm,10mm)`, etc.? Can I replace them with other options?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I could explain them, but I think it would be better if you take a look at first tutorials from TiKZ documentation. It's on your system `texdoc pgfmanual`. Another possibility could be searching in this site, there's nothing not previously explained here in my code.

Answer (score 7):

`pgfplots` generates color bars if you add the `colorbar` key to the axis environment. A horizontal colorbar is possible by means of `colorbar horizontal`.

Colorbars are (only) useful if there is some kind of "color data" in your axis: data which is mapped into a `colormap`. This is the case for `scatter`, `mesh`, `surf`, `contour`, and some other plot types. A simple example is show below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap/blackwhite,
        colorbar horizontal,
    ]
    \addplot[scatter] {rand};   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap/blackwhite,
        colorbar horizontal,
        colorbar sampled,
    ]
    \addplot[scatter] {rand};   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The example(s) use a black/white `colormap` and `colorbar horizontal`.

Note that I made two plots: one has `colorbar sampled`, a special key to generate non-continuous color bars as in your image.

More details can be found in the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I just wanted that colour bar, I mean, a colour bar which is not included in a plot.

Comment: Thanks for the note! In this case, I still hope that my answer helps others which search for related keywords.